# How Does Respond Know Not to Render A View

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I'm running into an issue with a Filter where the `respond` method is rendering a view, even though the content type is "application/json". I've verified this all the way to the `JSON.java` class through the debugger. But after calling `chain.doFilter()` in my Filter, something is still triggering the `GroovyPagesServlet` to try and find a view, which it can't find so it is returning a 404.

My question is basically, ignoring my Filter, what mechanism in grails says if I'm rendering JSON content, don't render a view? I may figure out if I know that, maybe I can trigger that in Filter somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user agent matches one of those specified at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.0.4/grails-plugin-mimetypes/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/mime/HttpServletResponseExtension.groovy#L63 then the accept header is ignored.  The `format` request parameter is most often the way the response type is handled.

Comment: Yea, we've tried various user-agents as well as the format parameter. There's something else going on and it is likely due to the fact that we are using a response wrapper. Just can't get enough of the internal figured out to determine why grails still wants to render a gsp.

Comment: If I add the gsp, then everything works. It returns a 200 with the JSON response (instead of HTML), which makes it even more of a mystery to me.